# What types of regex DO support (e.g.) negative lookbehind?

Tags: bash, find, regular-expression, gnu

**Bash on GNU:**

I am using a collection of `find` commands, most of which employ `-regex` to do their matching. Each time I try a different feature in my regex I have to cycle through the values for `-regextype` until one works. My particular need in this case is for one that supports negative lookbehind. It's hard to validate the (zero) results of my tests on this feature so I would like to simply refer to a list rather than repeating increasing series of tests.

I have found many references to Javascript and other platforms *not* supporting negative lookbehind, but I can't seem to find a central location for those which *do*.

<sub>It would be nice to see a chart somewhere listing many of the popular regex styles and the features they do and do not support, but I couldn't find that either.</sub>

Comment: I knew just a *perl* invocation of regex to support lookbehind (negative included). I have met it in **grep** with `-P` option but not sure for **find** and other command. Format of expressions you can find in `man pcre`. But I am sure that for more cases there are many ways to omit pcre usage in find or somewhere else.

Comment: more information on the "regextype" types at https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/Regular-expression-syntaxes.html#Regular-expression-syntaxes

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines)! Also, [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y) for an overview.

Comment: @Gilles That is a good chart, but does it distinguish between the `-regextype` options for `find`? The man page lists "emacs (this is the default), posix-awk, posix-basic, posix-egrep and posix-extended".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a `find` whose `-regex` supports look-around operators à la `perl`, you can use ast-open's `find`:

```
$ find /etc -regex '.*(?<!g)shadow'
/etc/shadow
```

`-regextype` is specific to the GNU implementation of `find` and none of the regex types it supports have look-around operators AFAIK.